# Trouble extracting list of quotes from webpage using bs4 and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to use bs4 to navigate to a webpage and extract all the quotes on the page into a list.

I also want to extract the total number of pages of that specific person (an element on the bottom of the page)

The code I am currently using is this.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

listOfQuotes = []
website = "https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/nassim-nicholas-taleb-quotes"
req = Request(website, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
s = soup(webpage,"html.parser")
div_container = s.findAll("div", {"id":"quotesList"})
```

I am having issues searching the `div_container` object of the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to find them by the title (all quotes have):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/nassim-nicholas-taleb-quotes"r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# We bring all the "a" that has the title "view quote"
all_a_quotes = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"title": "view quote"})
for a in all_a_quotes:
    # do something...
    print(a.text)
```

This will output (60 in total):

```
I'm in favour of religion as a tamer of arrogance. For a Greek Orthodox, the idea of God as creator outside the human is not God in God's terms. My God isn't the God of George Bush.
You are rich if and only if money you refuse tastes better than money you accept.
If you take risks and face your fate with dignity, there is nothing you can do that makes you small; if you don't take risks, there is nothing you can do that makes you grand, nothing.
Steve Jobs, Bill Gates and Mark Zuckerberg didn't finish college. Too much emphasis is placed on formal education - I told my children not to worry about their grades but to enjoy learning.
[...]
Debt is a mistake between lender and borrower, and both should suffer.
Capitalism is about adventurers who get harmed by their mistakes, not people who harm others with their mistakes.
The next time you experience a blackout, take some solace by looking at the sky. You will not recognize it.
```

For pagination we look if the last element "ul" exists (if it does not exist it only has one page), and if it exists we count how many "li" it has and we subtract 2:

```py
pagination = soup.select('ul[class*="pagination"]')
if not pagination:
    pages = 0
else:
    # we subtract two, that of next and that of previous 
    pages = len(pagination[0].find_all("li")) - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First time helping so I apologize if it isn’t the greatest.  I am a Python newb so I find it helpful to print and save to files to see what the program is seeing.
I do this with the following code:

```
#This open a file and sets it in “w or “write” mode. If 'export.txt' doesn't exist Python creates it!
file1 = open('export.txt', 'w')
#This writes whatever I want to the file.
file1.write("This is what I want in the file")
#This safely closes the file.
file1.close()
```

Applying this to your code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

listOfQuotes = []
website = "https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/nassim-nicholas-taleb-quotes"
req = Request(website, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
s = soup(webpage,"html.parser")
div_container = s.findAll("div", {"id":"quotesList"})

#because of findAll, I could not do file1.write(div_container) and instead had to iterate through each item in the list.
#findAll returns a type "bs4.element.ResultSet" which can't have .text on the end.  However, by calling each item in the "bs4.element.ResultSet" by index, you can then apply .text to it.
#in this case there is only one element.  That is to say, div_container[1] doesn't exist.
for i in range(len(div_container)):
    file1 = open('export.txt', 'w')
    #the .text returns just the text inside of the tag with none of the html coding.
    file1.write(div_container[i].text)
    file1.close()
```

This gives us the following:

> I'm in favour of religion as a tamer of arrogance. For a Greek
> Orthodox, the idea of God as creator outside the human is not God in
> God's terms. My God isn't the God of George Bush. Nassim Nicholas
> Taleb
>
> God Religion Arrogance etc.

So what is going on here?

If we run the code again, but instead of looking at the divs we look at the actual HTML using BS4's prettify method, like so:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

listOfQuotes = []
website = "https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/nassim-nicholas-taleb-quotes"
req = Request(website, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
#.prettify() is here
s = soup(webpage,"html.parser").prettify()
file1 = open('export2.txt', 'w')
file1.write(s)
file1.close()
```

we can look at the text document and see what Python is seeing and a snip of this is:

```
   <div class="bq_center ql_page">
    <div class="reflow_body bq_center">
     <div class="new-msnry-grid bqcpx grid-layout-hide" id="quotesList">
      <div class="m-brick grid-item boxy clearfix bqQt r-width" id="qpos_1_1">
       <a class="b-qt qt_530963 oncl_q" href="/quotes/nassim_nicholas_taleb_530963" title="view quote">
        I'm in favour of religion as a tamer of arrogance. For a Greek Orthodox, the idea of God as creator outside the human is not God in God's terms. My God isn't the God of George Bush.
       </a>
       <a class="bq-aut qa_530963 oncl_a" href="/quotes/nassim_nicholas_taleb_530963" title="view author">
        Nassim Nicholas Taleb
       </a>
       <div class="qbn-box">
        <div class="sh-cont">
         <a aria-label="Share this quote on Facebook" class="sh-fb sh-grey" href="/share/fb/530963" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <img alt="Share on Facebook" class="bq-fa" src="/st/img/4341377/fa/facebook-f.svg"/>
         </a>
         <a aria-label="Share this quote on Twitter" class="sh-tw sh-grey" href="/share/tw/530963?ti=Nassim+Nicholas+Taleb+Quotes" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <img alt="Share on Twitter" class="bq-fa" src="/st/img/4341377/fa/twitter.svg"/>
         </a>
         <a aria-label="Share this quote on LinkedIn" class="sh-tw sh-grey" href="/share/li/530963?ti=Nassim+Nicholas+Taleb+Quotes+-+BrainyQuote" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <img alt="Share on LinkedIn" class="bq-fa" src="/st/img/4341377/fa/linkedin-in.svg"/>
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="kw-box">
        <a class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_klc" data-idx="0" href="/topics/god-quotes">
         God
        </a>
        <a class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_klc" data-idx="1" href="/topics/religion-quotes">
         Religion
        </a>
        <a class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_klc" data-idx="2" href="/topics/arrogance-quotes">
         Arrogance
        </a>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Why is this important for you? Because you are pulling all divs, which trimmed down to just the div's containing text is:

```
  <div class="m-brick grid-item boxy clearfix bqQt r-width" id="qpos_1_1">
   <a class="b-qt qt_530963 oncl_q" href="/quotes/nassim_nicholas_taleb_530963" title="view quote">
    I'm in favour of religion as a tamer of arrogance. For a Greek Orthodox, the idea of God as creator outside the human is not God in God's terms. My God isn't the God of George Bush.
   </a>
   <a class="bq-aut qa_530963 oncl_a" href="/quotes/nassim_nicholas_taleb_530963" title="view author">
    Nassim Nicholas Taleb
   </a>
   <div class="kw-box">
    <a class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_klc" data-idx="0" href="/topics/god-quotes">
     God
    </a>
    <a class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_klc" data-idx="1" href="/topics/religion-quotes">
     Religion
    </a>
    <a class="qkw-btn btn btn-xs oncl_klc" data-idx="2" href="/topics/arrogance-quotes">
     Arrogance
  </div>
```

This is where we need to think about how best to get the information.  We see it is in a div tag, and also an a tag.  But if we pull that we are going to end up grabbing the same things again, so we need to find something that is unique to the quote but not the other stuff.

So if we look back at the 2nd export, and compare the a tags around the quote:

```
<a class="b-qt qt_530963 oncl_q" href="/quotes/nassim_nicholas_taleb_530963" title="view quote">
<a class="b-qt qt_531016 oncl_q" href="/quotes/nassim_nicholas_taleb_531016" title="view quote">
```

We can see the class and href portions change each time and won't be of much help, however the information in the title stays the same so we can use that. Once more, using your code as a template:

```
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    
    listOfQuotes = []
    website = "https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/nassim-nicholas-taleb-quotes"
    req = Request(website, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    s = soup(webpage,"html.parser")
    quotes = s.find_all("a", attrs={"title": "view quote"})
    for a in quotes:
        listOfQuotes.append(a.text)

print(listOfQuotes)
```

For the second part of your question, I would use what Lucas before me said, however I have adapted it to your code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

listOfQuotes = []
website = "https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/nassim-nicholas-taleb-quotes"
req = Request(website, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
s = soup(webpage,"html.parser")
# We bring all the "a" that has the title "view quote"
quotes = s.find_all("a", attrs={"title": "view quote"})
for a in quotes:
    # do something...
    listOfQuotes.append(a.text)

pagination = s.select('ul[class*="pagination"]')
if not pagination:
    pages = 0
else:
    # we subtract two, that of next and that of previous 
    pages = len(pagination[0].find_all("li")) - 2
```